# Any ideas why I am getting an $().progessbar is not a function in my MVC application

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

Here is the actual error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
$(...).progressbar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (microsite.js:21)
```

Here is where my scripts js are defined in tmy header:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/microsite.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

and here is the actual code in error from microsite.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pledgeBar').progressbar({
        disabled: true,
        change: function () {
            var val = $(this).progressbar("option", "value") || 0;
            var valTxt = '' + val;
            valTxt = valTxt.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
            var percentVal = 0
            if ($(this).progressbar("option", "max") != 100) {
                percentVal = val / $(this).progressbar("option", "max") * 100;
            }
            if (percentVal < 15) {
                $(this).find('.ui-progressbar-value').html('<div class="label label-reverse hidden-xs"><img src="/common/images/GreatAmericanCampout/pledgebar-indicator.png" width="17" height="10" alt="goal indicator" /> ' + valTxt + '</div>');
            } else {
                $(this).find('.ui-progressbar-value').html('<div class="label hidden-xs">' + valTxt + '<img src="/common/images/GreatAmericanCampout/pledgebar-indicator.png" width="17" height="10" alt="goal indicator" /></div>');
            }
            var maxTxt = '' + $('#pledgeBar').progressbar("option", "max");
            $('.thermometer .goal').html(maxTxt.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '<br/>campers');
        }
    });

    if (pledgeBarConfig != undefined) {
        $('#pledgeBar').progressbar("option", "disabled", false);
        $('#pledgeBar').progressbar("option", "max", pledgeBarConfig.max); // update the max
        $('#pledgeBar').progressbar("option", "value", pledgeBarConfig.val); // update the value
    };
});
```

I have taken off the $(document.ready) off but still I keep getting this same error.

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: which of the various JS libraries you've loaded is meant to contain the progressbar widget? The error is saying there is no such thing anywhere in your code. Are you sure you loaded the right files?

Comment: is progressBar a plugin?

Comment: `bootstrap.js` doesn't have a `.progressbar` function, and that looks to be the only library loaded before `microsite.js`; make sure the code containing the `progressbar()` function is loaded prior to loading any code that calls it.

Comment: If you are using the progress bar from jQuery UI you need to load jQuery UI. And make sure you load it after jQuery. https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Thank you these are all great comments. I will let you know when I solve the issue

Comment: I have corrected this by adding the jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js to the my head of my page. Note: I thought originally that these were included in my jquery-min already, my bad.